# Zend-framework 1.12 module: links always lead to default module

Tags: zend-framework, url, module

I created ZendFramework 1.12 applications with modules.
The idea was to have versions of the API in modules, with RESTfull paths.

The default module was V1, and now when I am trying to create v1s1 module, all links still lead to V1.

Can anybody push me in the right direction how to solve this?

**MORE DETAILS**

This is the code I have to use modules.

`application.ini`

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "v1"
resources.modules[] =

v1.boostrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/v1/Bootstrap.php"

resources.frontController.plugins.putHandler = Zend_Controller_Plugin_PutHandler
routes.rest.type = Zend_Rest_Route
routes.rest.defaults.module = v1
```

Main `Bootstrap.php`:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

    protected function _initAppAutoload()
    {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => 'V1s1',
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/v1s1',
        ));
        $autoloader->addResourceType('model', 'models', 'Model');
        return $autoloader;
    }

}
```

V1 `Bootstrap.php`:

```
class V1_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
    protected $_moduleName = "v1";

    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        // Add autoloader empty namespace
        $autoLoader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
        $autoLoader->registerNamespace('v1_');

        return $autoLoader;
    }

    protected function _initResourceLoader()
    {
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/v1/controllers/helpers');
    }

    public function _initRouts()
    {
        $front     = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $restRoute = new Zend_Rest_Route($front, array(), $arrayOfControllers));
        $front->getRouter()->addRoute('rest', $restRoute);
    }

}
```

Now I need to create module v2, but when I do that, I everything crashes. Link are no longer RESTfull, and every link still leads to the V1 module.  V2 module Bootstrap.php is being accessed.

Comment: Can you explain more your problem?

Comment: I added a part of my code in the question. I am not sure how to explain more what my problem is, I am just unable to create two modules with REST routes.